# Functionalizing CTAC stabilized nanoparticles

Tags: coordination-compounds, stability, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology, surfactants

I am working on functionalizing silver-gold bimetallic nanoparticles. My nanoparticles are stabilized by CTAC(cetyltrimethylammonium chloride).The most articles which I found, are about the functionalizing of citrate stabilized nanoparticles.
Is functionalizing CTAC stabilized nanoparticles more difficult than citrate stabilized nanoparticles?